# css absolute positioned elements overlap their overflow parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a huge table that needs to be horizontal scrollable and an absolute position list inside a `<td>`,  if the list is too long, it will be hidden by the table. So how can I use overflow-x and have the list visible at the same time.

I think the snippet explains it clearly.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
td {
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.table-wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  overflow-y: visible;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.table2-wrapper {
  width: 100px;
/*   overflow-x: scroll; */
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  top: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #1e90ff;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Letters</th>
          <th>Drinks</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="parent">A
            <div class="child">
              <ul>
                <li>Aa</li>
                <li>Ab</li>
                <li>Ac</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>Coffee</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>Tea</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div>
I only need the horizontal scroll bar, and I want the list to be visible!
</div>

<div class="table2-wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Letters</th>
          <th>Drinks</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="parent">A
            <div class="child">
              <ul>
                <li>Aa</li>
                <li>Ab</li>
                <li>Ac</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>Coffee</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>Tea</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

This article actually solves the problem, but the list won't follow the table on scroll anymore.
https://front-back.com/how-to-make-absolute-positioned-elements-overlap-their-overflow-hidden-parent/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

All you need to do is to give your table a `min-height`. so I just set it to `min-height: 200px;`

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
td {
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.table-wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 200px; /* Add This */
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  top: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid #1e90ff;
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Letters</th>
          <th>Drinks</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="parent">A
            <div class="child">
              <ul>
                <li>Aa</li>
                <li>Ab</li>
                <li>Ac</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </td>
          <td>Coffee</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>B</td>
          <td>Tea</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this kind of works, but not perfect because my list can be really long, like having 100 - 200 items. I will probably use this solution and limit the length of my list if there no other options.

Comment: Cool, let me know if you need anything else on that can be improved on this answer

Comment: actually, Is there any way that the list can overlap the table? because just below the table I have some buttons that I don't want them to be pushed away.

Comment: Look, I am pretty sure there's a better way of approaching what you're trying to achieve. Can you post a picture of your desired result and I'll suggest a better html setup for it because the way you're doing it, is quite questionable.

Comment: The list is even hiding the data on the `<tr>` below it. So I am not sure why you'd want to do that.